# WaitForExit for a process on a remote computer

Tags: c#, process

I'm using [WMI to start a process on a remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677867/run-application-or-process-on-a-remote-computer). The call to create the process returns immediately and I also get the id of the process on the remote machine.

I would like to wait for the remote process to be completed. One option would be to poll whether a process on the remote machine with the given id still exists.

However, I was wondering whether there is a better way to achieve this, maybe using native WinAPI functions?

Just for additional information, this is the code that I am currently using to start the remote process:

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;

connOptions.Username = domainUserName;
connOptions.Password = password;

ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", host), connOptions);
manScope.Connect();

ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["CommandLine"] = commandLine;

ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how effective this can be, you can use [ManagementEventWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx) to watch a query.

Here is something I found on the net.

```
WqlEventQuery wQuery = 
 new WqlEventQuery("Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'");

using (ManagementEventWatcher wWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, wQuery))
{    
  bool stopped = false;

  while (stopped == false)
  {
    using (ManagementBaseObject MBOobj = wWatcher.WaitForNextEvent())
    {
      if (((ManagementBaseObject)MBOobj["TargetInstance"])["ProcessID"].ToString() == ProcID)
      {
        // the process has stopped
        stopped = true;
      }
    }
  }

  wWatcher.Stop();
}
```

Comment: u should wrap  wWatcher and MBOobj in a "using" statemen

Answer (score 2):

The native Win32 way of achieving this would be to perform a `WaitForSingleObject()` on the process handle returned by `CreateProcess()`, however I don't think this handle is made available to you from WMI.

[This article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/dec06/hey1208.mspx) offers another option you could consider - instead of polling the process list and waiting for your process to disappear, it repeatedly queries for process deletion events matching your process ID:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
objWMIService.Create "notepad.exe", null, null, intProcessID

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredProcesses = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'")

Do Until i = 1
    Set objLatestProcess = colMonitoredProcesses.NextEvent
    If objLatestProcess.TargetInstance.ProcessID = intProcessID Then
        i = 1
    End If
Loop
```

---

You could also improve on this by using a `ManagementEventWatcher` object and its `WaitForNextEvent` method to avoid having to poll for the deletion events.

Answer (score 1):

If the process on the remote machine is your code then you could open up a socket on the calling machine and let the remote machine 'ping' it when it has finished.

If you want to use this method for any remote process you could have a helper app/service on the remote computer that monitors your process and returns the completed ping.

Comment: That's a nice idea, thanks. This would probably be most efficient and quite simple. However, I would like to keep it as generic as possible so I can start any process remotely.

Answer (score -1):

I havent had chance to check this yet,

int pid = (int)managementBaseObject["processId"];

Process remPrc = Process.GetProcessById(pid, RemoteMachine);

remPrc.WaitForExit();

Comment: WaitForExit() is not supported for remote process!